# Matplot histogram results in lots of lines

Tags: python, histogram, nan

I am trying to plot a histogram of monthly return data.  There are 78 observations, preceded by 73 blanks (in Excel) or NaNs in the DataFrame.  When I try and plot the histogram it results in a figure with lots of vertical lines going from 0.0 to 1.0 with colourful lines evenly spaced between (which I take to mean I'm doing something wrong).

The DataFrame that I'm working with looks like this:

```
date
2009-03-31       NaN
2009-04-30       NaN
2009-05-31       NaN
               ...  
2017-01-31     0.45%
2017-02-28     3.33%
2017-03-31    -1.55%
```

I've tried re-specifying every argument in the plt.hist() function, different numbers of bins, different ranges, and some forms of "dropna", but haven't been able to resolve.

```
df['column'].hist(bins=20)
plt.plot
```

I'm expecting a distribution of monthly returns ranging from around -10% to +10% which is somewhat normal.  What I actually get is just a grid with fine vertical lines, with colourful lines evenly distributed (I assume these are the bins).  There is no error message.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, your data has the following format:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2009-03-31', '2009-04-30', '2009-05-31'], 
'val':[0.0045, 0.0333,  -0.0155]})
```

(you can transform percentages to float by applying this function: f= lambda x: float(x.strip('%'))/100)

```py
ax = df.plot.bar(x='date', y='val', rot=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes - that format is correct.  Sorry, do I need to translate the percentages to float for the charts to work?